# Crossrider: external db?

Tags: crossrider

Is it possible to access Sql Server instance from Crossrider?
It has doc for local db and i am assuming that is used to store data on the browser's machine.
I have central data that gets constantly updated/read by plugin users and need a way to access external db (preferrably Sql Server but i am flexible).
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crossrider does not provide a native way to interact with SQL servers (or any other external database), and you are correct about our [local db](http://docs.crossrider.com/staging/#!/api/appAPI.db) support.

However, if you have the HTTP URLs for accessing your db, you can use the [appAPI.request.get](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request-method-get) and [appAPI.request.post](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request-method-post) methods to interact with your database.

Comment: Shlomo, you have a typo in documentation: "A requestis considered successful if it returns any of the following HTTP response codes: 200-207, 226." ...  It should be "request is" not "requestis"

Comment: Thank you ... the documentation has been corrected accordingly.